# Rank-constrained least-squares solution of the Sylvester matrix equation

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, least-squares

For the [Sylvester matrix equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $AX+XB=C$, I want to find the least-squares solution $X$ via

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| AX + XB - C \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mbox{rank} (X) \leq k\end{array}$$

I searched broadly online but couldn't find any literature on this. When dealing with a rank constraint, I think that we will use the [Eckart-Young Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) somewhere. However, if we solve the Sylvester equation without the rank constraint using the Kronecker product, it's hard to deal with the rank of $X$ when $X$ is in vectorized form. I also tried to do SVD on $A$ and $B$ but could not proceed either.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem? Or is there literature on this already? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the work of [Beckermann and Townsend.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09494)

*Beckermann, Bernhard; Townsend, Alex*, [**On the singular values of matrices with displacement structure**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/16M1096426),  [ZBL06803120](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06803120).

Comment: Thanks, I have read the main theorem, and I think here I want the least square solution, and therefore I don't need the Sylvester equation to hold exactly. Also the rank here is exact, not numerical rank.

Comment: @XavierXiao You have changed the question.